# NavigationView setNavigationItemSelectedListener this API is marked as internal to the support library and should not be accessed from apps

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*Ini UI*/

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(t);
        setupToolbar();

        mNavigationRv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_rv);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv);

        mNavigationRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        mNavigationAdapter = new NavigationAdapter(new ArrayList<String>(), this, this);
        mNavigationRv.setAdapter(mNavigationAdapter);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, 0, 0);
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Android studio gives me an error

> "This API is marked as internal for the support library and should not
>   be accessed from apps"

for `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` and `setCheckedItem`.

Help please.

Comment: show us more code where you are implementing this...

Comment: I have update the question.Thanks.

Comment: What version of Android Support Library are you using?

Comment: I use the latest version 25.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same here after updating to `Support Library 25.0.1`.

This is a warning and it goes for all public methods of `NavigationView` but it's annoying because Android Studio marks it as errors.

`@SuppressWarnings("RestrictedApi")` resolves it for now.

**EDIT**
It looks like it was the problem with Android Studio not Support Library.
With AS 2.3 Canary 3 I don't see any warnings.

Comment: it seems this is the only solution for now.Thanks for your help.